# jquery .children() of .get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, children, traversal

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can use `$('ul').children('li').get(0);` to get the list item. How can I use `.children('a')` to traverse down the tree?

I tried something like `$('ul').children('li').get(0).children('a');` but that does not work.

---

For future reference:

1. I will be doing other things to the `li` other than traversing down
   to the `a`, which is why I am trying to use `.children()`.
2. Index will be dynamic and not always 0.

Which is why .eq() is the preferred answer. Now I can do something like:

```
_load = function(index) {
  image_get = thumbs.children('li').eq(index);

  [...]

  $(function() {
    var img = $(new Image());
    img
      .load(function() {
        [...]
      }
      .attr('src', image_get.children('a').attr('href'));
  });
}

_load(0);
```

^^^ WIP. Code unfinished.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.get()` returns a DOM Element. You can wrap it back in a jQuery object like:

```
$($('ul').children('li').get(0)).children('a');
```

**But** I think what you really want is [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$('ul').children('li').eq(0).children('a');
```

**Edit**

As Reid kindly pointed out in the comment below,

`$('ul').children('li').eq(0).children('a');`

is semantically equivalent to the more concise :

`$('ul > li:first-child > a');`

which does the same as the above with a single selector.

Comment: I would even go so far as `$('ul > li:first-child > a')` to emulate that above snippet.

Comment: @Reid It's true that that selector does the same thing :) But I think it is important to explain the difference between `.get()` and `.eq()` to gavsiu. He may want to do something like `.eq(3)` in the future (or now) too for all we know.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. They should really put a link between .index() and .eq().

Comment: @gavsiu Agreed. I used to use `.get()` and wrap it in a jQuery object like my first example for about 6 months before I realized that there was `.eq()`. Anyways, I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just put it all in the selector and let that do all the work for you:

```
$('ul li:first a')
```

This will get a jQuery object for the first `<a>` tag in your sample HTML.

The selector logic works like this:  Find all ul tags, the find the first li tag in each, then get all the a tags in each of the first li tags.  The result is a jQuery selection which you can then apply various operations to.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5qZP5/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

`$('ul li a:first');`

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/yCAT6/

`$('ul li a');` returns all of the `a`s in that list.

`:first` filters for just the first.